# JS - Fill an associative array using a loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to fill an JS array using a loop but is not working
This is my code:

```
words = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];
words_formated = [];

for( var i=0 ; i<words.length ; i++ ){
    words_formated.push({words[i]: "<i>"+ words[i] +"</i>"});
}
```

Comment: The syntax for arrays is `[...]`

Comment: try with words = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also got an error with trying to use the array key to directly assign the object property name, this worked:

```
words = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];
words_formated = [];

for( var i=0; i<words.length; i++ ){
    var item = words[i]
    words_formated.push({item: "<i>"+ words[i] +"</i>"});
}
```

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z3yM8/)

Answer (score 1):

As your are pushing an object into array `words_formated.push({words[i]: "<i>"+ words[i] +"</i>"});` , the key name `words[i]` is not correct

The problem will get solved if you write

`words_formated.push({words: "<i>"+ words[i] +"</i>"});`

and its best practice if you define `word` array correctly as `words = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var words = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'],
    words_formated = [],
    item;
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    item = {};
    item[words[i]] = '<i>' + words[i] + '</i>';
    words_formated.push(item);
}
```

According to your own code, the result will be :

```
[
    { one   : "<i>one</i>"   }, 
    { two   : "<i>two</i>"   }, 
    { three : "<i>three</i>" }, 
    { four  : "<i>four</i>"  }
]
```

Array :

```
var a = (1, 2, 3); // a sequence of numbers (returns the last one)
a // 3
var a = [1, 2, 3]; // an array
a // [1, 2, 3]
```

Fails :

```
var k = ['name'];
var o = { k[0]: 'value' }; // SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
```

Passes :

```
var k = ['name'];
var o = {};
o[k[0]] = 'value';
o // Object {name: "value"}
```

Comment: Your solution is working as well. Very useful your explanation to use  array / object . Thank you

Comment: sorry, I was not paying attention. I'm using: `code`var item = words[i]
    words_formated.push({item: "<i>"+ words[i] +"</i>"})`code`

Comment: I think your solution is putting js objects in the array, isn't it?

Comment: @bito_ This is my last try. Which result do you want (choose a number) : **#1** `[{item:'<i>one</i>'}]`, **#2** `[{one:'<i>one</i>'}]` or **#3** `[{words:'<i>one</i>'}]`?

Comment: according to your choices I choose `[{one:'<i>one</i>'}]`

Comment: @bito_ Phew!! So, the only acceptable answer is mine! All other answers do NOT give you the proper result. Well, do what you want to, I don't care anymore, I have my answer. Thanks =D

Comment: I'm reviewing this post and I have to say you are completly right - according with what I wanted but it was me who didn't make the appropraite question, I mean that the answer considered right was for the my specific case / question.  Nonetheless, I already solved my problem.
I'd like to mark your answer as useful but I don't have enough reputation. Sorry and thank you very much!

Comment: @bito_ Thanks for the reply. I really appreciate and take it as a reward :) I've just voted up two of your questions in order for you to be able to vote up : http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
words = ("one", "two", "three", "four"); //wrong
```

Instead use within array block

```
words = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like an array:

```
words = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];
var words_formated=[];

for( var i=0 ; i<words.length ; i++ ){

    words_formated[words[i]]= "<i>"+ words[i] +"</i>";
}

console.log(words_formated);
```

Comment: Look at this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a3mCu/ Press run for test it. It works...

Comment: If I try to 'stringify' your array I'll receive an empty array: `alert(JSON.stringify(words_formated));`  unless we declare words_formated as an object - `var words_formated={}; `  Thank you